# Can I use "this.props" in componentDidMount? Error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

In componentDidMount to `selectTodo`, assign `this.props.selected`. In the console, I check that selectTodo is an object that contains an array of `comments`. I am trying to get to this array but I get an error: Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'map' of undefined

```
class Details extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();


    this.state = {
      resul: []
      selectTodo:[]
    }; 
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(" http://....../todos")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          resul: response.data,
          selectTodo: this.props.selected
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error fetching and parsing data', Error);
      }
    );
  }


  render () {

    return (
      <div>    
        {
          { 
              this.state.selectTodo.comments.map((obj, i) => {
                return <li>{obj["comment"]}</li>
              })  
            } 
        }
      </div>      
    );
  }
}



export default Details;
```

**Console.log**

```
 console.log(this.state.selectTodo);


 return:


Object
  comments: (2) [{'comment': 'sdsd'}, {'comment': 'sdsdsdsds'}]
  id: 1
```

> Error:
>         Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: change your state to selectTodo: { comments: [] }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, the data that you define in `state` and loop in the `render` does not look good for me. I mean, you define `selecTodo` as an array in `constructor` and trying to get as `selectTodo.comments` in the `render` method. So, change the state to

```
    this.state = {
      resul: []
      selectTodo:{comments: []}
    };
```

And change the way you assign the data in `componentDidMount` as

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(" http://....../todos")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          resul: response.data,
          selectTodo: { comments: this.props.selected.comments }
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error fetching and parsing data', Error);
      }
    );
  }
```

and do the following in `render`

```
  render () {
    if(!this.state.selectedTodo.comments.length) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <div>    
        {
          { 
              this.state.selectTodo.comments.map((obj, i) => {
                return <li>{obj["comment"]}</li>
              })  
            } 
        }
      </div>      
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

the undefined comes from the fact that componentDidMount happens after the first render, so when the first render occurs this.state.selectTodo is still undefined.

One way of solving that is inside the render checking if this.state.selectTodo exists and only if it exists return the div with the map, otherwise return a spinner or something else.

Does this make sense?